# how to make the parameters of a method generic

Tags: java, object, methods

I should create a method inside my class that can accept two different types of objects as parameters, then in the method I should check which parameter I received and do the following operations. ex:

```
public void check(Object obj){
   if(obj istanceOf MyClassOne)
      ...
   else if(obj istanceOf MyClassTwo)
      ...
```

How should i handle it?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Also, perhaps overloaded method instead of generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not evident.

Consider the following example:

```
interface I {
    default void print(String method) {
        System.out.println(method + " => " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}

static class A implements I {}
static class A2 extends A {}
static class B implements I {}

static void print(A a) {
    a.print("print(A)");
}

static void print(A2 a2) {
    a2.print("print(A2)");
}

static void print(I i) {
    i.print("print(I)");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(new A());
    print(new A2());
    print(new B());
}
```

with output

```
print(A) => Test.A
print(A2) => Test.A2
print(I) => Test.B
```

the [polymorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) method `print` admit explicitly `A`, `A2` and `I` types.

Every type injected to `print` will use the less generic form of `print` polymorphism. That is why `print(new A2());` use `A2` form although any form is valid for this type.

**BUT**, it is correct **only** in compile time, at runtime this is not true.

Consider the following example:

```
A a2_really = (A) new A2();
print(a2_really);
```

the injected object is **A2** but, what method will be used?

```
print(A) => Test.A2
```

since it is resolved at compile time, at runtime `A` form will be used.

Conclusion:

- if you want to enforce the use of one or other method at compile time, you can write a polymorphic method.
- if you want to check the **instanced method** (the object created at runtime), use reflection or encode your logic using other structs (like interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

You can use method overloading if the classes are not super/subclasses of each other:

```java
public void check(MyClassOne obj) {
    ....
}
public void check(MyClassTwo obj) {
    ....
}
```

When you call `check(someMyClassOne)`, then it will compile to use the first method, and for `check(someMyClassTwo)`, it will compile to use the second method. Note that this is mostly convenient when the types are known at the place where you call the `check` method, otherwise you do indeed need to either make all objects you'd like to check extend a common interface or check what they are instance of as you were already doing.

Comment: If one class extends the other, your code could produce different behavior at compile time or runtime. (See my answer).